# Is there a fundamental limitation on how rapidly (with voltage) can a diode ’switch’ ? If so, can you pinpoint its origin?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

Is there a fundamental limitation on how rapidly (with voltage) can a diode ’switch’ ? If so, can you pinpoint its origin?
The diode here is a 1N914

Comment: Any dynamic system are limited in their speed of switching state, that is basic physics. The only component that I can think of that isn`t affect by dynamic is an ideal resistance.

Comment: trr for a 1N914 is something like 4ns there's also a few pF of capacitance. If you want faster there are much lower capacitance diodes and faster ones too.

Comment: Reverse recovery effect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A diode is "on" when there are charge carriers in what is normally its depletion region, and "off" when the depletion region exists.

Therefore, the fundamental limitation on switching speed is how fast those carriers can move into or out of the depletion region. This relates to the mobility of the carriers and the magnitude of the E field across the region.

The capacitance of the junction itself, along with any stray (parasitic) capacitances put a limit on how fast you can cause the E field to change in the first place.

Comment: Agreed, the "fundamental limitation" here is the doped semi conductor regions of material (the P and N layers) and their ability to carry charge.

Comment: Is it greater or less for a breakdown diode? What is the approximate value of it?

Comment: Greater or less than the 1N914? That would depend on the specific diode, but probably greater, since breakdown (Zener) diodes tend to be more heavily doped, resulting in greater charge carrier density and greater capacitance. The fastest diodes have lighter doping to reduce both the charge carrier density and the junction capacitance.

Comment: I think that turning off can take longer than turning on, because to turn off the carriers have to diffuse out of the junction.  I recall a nice J. Williams app note... I have no idea of what number.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a parasitic capacitance in the diode which limits the switching time. If it's too short, then the signal will be distorted.

This can be found in its datasheet:

http://www.vishay.com/docs/85622/1n914.pdf

> Reverse recovery time = 4ns

Answer (score 0):

The legs of the diode have inductance (the current will flow in a loop;-) and the depletion region will have capacitance. There can also be resistance in the legs. These, as a minimum will slow down the switching transients . (There are other effects as well which can further delay the switching).